# KeyError: 'a' while writing a program in python

Tags: python

```
   a=input('enter the name\n')
   b=input('enter the age\n')

   print('your name is {a} and your age is {b}'.format(a,b))
```

I am running above piece of code and I am getting below error in python:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
    print('your name is {a} and your age is {b}'.format(a,b))
KeyError: 'a'
```

Comment: `print('your name is {0} and your age is {1}'.format(a,b))` 0 and 1 is the index value.

Comment: Or if you want to use names they have to be _keyword_, not positional, arguments.

Answer (score 3):

you're combining two different syntax. try one of the following:

```
print('your name is {} and your age is {}'.format(a,b))
```

or

```
print(f'your name is {a} and your age is {b}')  # notice the f in the begining
```

Comment: Also possible: ``print('your name is {a} and your age is {b}'.format(a=a,b=b))`` (not saying it's recommended). And for completeness: ``print('your name is {a} and your age is {b}'.format(**{"a":a,"b":b}))``